# Find inverse of matrix using Cayley Hamilton Theorem using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math

I have understood how to prove CHT using MATLAB but unable to find how to find inverse using it i.e post-multiplying by A^-1 in characteristic equation and then finding the value of the inverse.

This is how far i have gotten so far:

```
A=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
p=char(A);
poly2str(p,'x')
polyvalm(p,A)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do with your code and what this has to with the problem at hand. For instance, `char(A)` is the matrix A turned into a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html).

Comment: For details on how to get the inverse using Cayley Hamilton theorem, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2835881/81360) for instance. I would recommend that you get the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial and apply the formula from the top answer.